# Serializing Face Features for recognition in DLIB

Tags: c++, serialization, dlib

I am writing a dlib code to do face recognition on 1 to 1 basis.

I followed the code sample in [dlib samples](http://dlib.net/dnn_face_recognition_ex.cpp.html) and did the following:

```
std::vector<matrix<rgb_pixel>> faces;
for (auto face : detector(img1))
{
    auto shape = sp(img1, face);
    matrix<rgb_pixel> face_chip;
    extract_image_chip(img1, get_face_chip_details(shape, 150, 0.25), face_chip);
    faces.push_back(move(face_chip));
}
```

this is for the first image and then did the same for the second image:

```
for (auto face : detector(img2))
{
    auto shape = sp(img2, face);
    matrix<rgb_pixel> face_chip;
    extract_image_chip(img2, get_face_chip_details(shape, 150, 0.25), face_chip);
    faces.push_back(move(face_chip));
}
```

then i continue  as per the mentioned link:

```
std::vector<matrix<float, 0, 1>> face_descriptors = net(faces);
std::vector<sample_pair> edges;
for (size_t i = 0; i < face_descriptors.size(); ++i)
{
     for (size_t j = i; j < face_descriptors.size(); ++j)
     {
          if (length(face_descriptors[i] - face_descriptors[j]) < threshold)
              edges.push_back(sample_pair(i, j));
     }
 }
 std::vector<unsigned long> labels;
 const int num_clusters = chinese_whispers(edges, labels);
//etc
```

and now comes my question. img1 is an image already available to the code that is read when i need to match a specific person. (ie if I want to mach personX, img1 is read using

```
load_image(img1, "personX.jpg");
```

Instead of having the image saved, i was trying to save the features and load them to reduce the time spent the extraction of features. so what I did is I moved the first for loop at a different function (enrollment like)  and made it something like this:

```
std::vector<matrix<rgb_pixel>> faces;
for (auto face : detector(img1))
{
    auto shape = sp(img1, face);
    matrix<rgb_pixel> face_chip;
    extract_image_chip(img1, get_face_chip_details(shape, 150, 0.25), face_chip);
    serialize("personX.dat") <<face_chip;
}
```

then at the recognition instead of the loop i used

```
matrix<rgb_pixel> face_chip;
deserialize("personX.dat")>>face_chip;            
faces.push_back(move(face_chip));
```

and the rest of the code from the extraction of img2 onward remained the same. the code compiled. But during execution when i reach the recognition i end up with the following error:

**************************** FATAL ERROR DETECTED ****************************

Error detected at line 216.
Error detected in file /usr/local/include/dlib/dnn/input.h.
Error detected in function void dlib::input_rgb_image_sized::to_tensor(forward_iterator, forward_iterator, dlib::resizable_tensor&) const [with forward_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >; long unsigned int NR = 150ul; long unsigned int NC = 150ul].

Failing expression was i->nr()==NR && i->nc()==NC    input_rgb_image_sized::to_tensor()

All input images must have 150 rows and 150 columns, but we got one with 0 rows and 0 columns.

Is there something wrong with the serialization / de-serialization? or should i do writing the features to a file with another method?

code for the full funtion:

```
try
{
    load_image(img1, check_image);
}
catch (...)
{
    cout<<"Name: "<<uname<<" doesn't exist"<<endl;
    return;
}

else
{
    QElapsedTimer timer;
    timer.start();


    dlib::assign_image(img2, dlib::cv_image<bgr_pixel>(colorImage));
    std::vector<matrix<rgb_pixel>> faces;

    for (auto face : detector(img1))
    {
        auto shape = sp(img1, face);
        matrix<rgb_pixel> face_chip;
        extract_image_chip(img1, get_face_chip_details(shape, 150, 0.25), face_chip);
        faces.push_back(move(face_chip));
//                serialize("out.dat")<<face_chip;   //used whin i dont need to read image
    }

//            matrix<rgb_pixel> face_chip; //used whin i dont need to read image
//            deserialize("out.dat")>>face_chip; //used whin i dont need to read image
//            faces.push_back(move(face_chip)); //used whin i dont need to read image

    cout<<"Time to extract features for enroled image: "<<timer.elapsed()<<endl;
    timer.restart();

    for (auto face : detector(img2))
    {
        auto shape = sp(img2, face);
        matrix<rgb_pixel> face_chip;
        extract_image_chip(img2, get_face_chip_details(shape, 150, 0.25), face_chip);
        faces.push_back(move(face_chip));
    }

    cout<<"Time to extract features for new image: "<<timer.elapsed()<<endl;
    timer.restart();

    if (faces.size() < 2)
    {
        cout<<"No Face"<<endl;
    }

    else
    {
        std::vector<matrix<float, 0, 1>> face_descriptors = net(faces);
        std::vector<sample_pair> edges;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < face_descriptors.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = i; j < face_descriptors.size(); ++j)
            {
                if (length(face_descriptors[i] - face_descriptors[j]) < threshold)
                    edges.push_back(sample_pair(i, j));
            }
        }
        std::vector<unsigned long> labels;
        const int num_clusters = chinese_whispers(edges, labels);

        if (num_clusters == 1)
        {
            cout<<"Recognized"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
                    cout<<"Faces don't match";
        }
    }

    cout<<"Needed time is: "<<timer.elapsed()<<" ms"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: can you link to a gist or something of the full src?  Also, are you sure your images are good (ie have a face and are the right size)?

Comment: i will post code as a reply concerning the images yes i am sure i have faces in them as if i don't use serialization i get the matching result correctly

Comment: i added the code to the question. the commented parts in the code are what i am hoping to use to avoid extraction of the image feature each time the matching is required for a person. so in short i want the features to be extracted. saved to a file then whenever i need to match that specific person i read his file and extract the features of the incoming image only and thus save half of he required time for matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of serializing the Matrix i serialized the output vector (faces).

```
serialize("personX.dat")<<faces;
```

then when doing the recognition i deserialized the dat file and used the resulting vector:

```
std::vector<matrix<rgb_pixel>> faces;
deserialize("out.dat")>>faces;
for (auto face : detector(img2))
{
    auto shape = sp(img2, face);
    matrix<rgb_pixel> face_chip;
    extract_image_chip(img2, get_face_chip_details(shape, 150, 0.25), face_chip);
    faces.push_back(move(face_chip));
}
```

and I continued as mentioned in the question.

I don't know if this is the best way to do it... but it worked.